# how to identify positions of max value in an array?

Tags: arrays, r, max

My array is

```
x <- array(1:24, dim=c(3,4,3))
```

My task 1 is to find the max value according to the first two dimensions

```
x.max <- apply(x,c(1,2), function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, max(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

in case there is NA data
    my task 2 is to find the max value position on the third dimension.
I tried

```
x.max.position = apply(x, c(1,2),which.max(x))
```

But this only give me the position on the fist two dimensions.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: @JackManey because the OP'er edited to show what they tried and they provided a reproducible example. +1 in my book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not totally clear, but if you want to find the `max` for each matrix of the third dimension (is that even a technically right thing to say?), then you need to use `apply` across the third dimension. The argument `margin` under `?apply` states that:

> a vector giving the subscripts which the function will be applied over. E.g., for a matrix 1 indicates rows, 2 indicates columns, c(1, 2) indicates rows and columns.

So for this example where you have a 3D array, `3` is the third dimension. So...

```
t( apply( x , 3 , function(x) which( x == max(x) , arr.ind = TRUE ) ) ) 
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    4
[2,]    3    4
[3,]    3    4
```

Which returns a matrix where each row contains the row and then column index of the max value of each 2D array/matrix of the third dimension.

If you want the `max` across *all* dimensions you can use `which` and the `arr.ind` argument like this:

```
which( x==max(x,na.rm=T) , arr.ind = T )
     dim1 dim2 dim3
[1,]    3    4    2
```

Which tells us the `max` value is the third row, fourth column, second matrix.

#### EDIT

To find the position at dim 3 where where values on dim 1 and 2 are max try:

```
which.max( apply( x , 3 , max ) )
# [1] 2
```

Which tells us that at position 2 of the third dimension contains the maximal value.

Comment: I tried these, but it did not give me the desired result. The result I want is the position at dim 3 where values on dim 1 and 2 are the maximum.

Comment: @Dan please add the desired result to the OP and don't edit the OP to include part of a proposed solution - it renders the answers posted useless!

Comment: Thanks, Simon. I get it. t( apply( x , 3 , function(x) which( x == max(x) , arr.ind = TRUE ) ) ) is what I want.