# How to get the index of the minimum value of an array

Tags: arrays, r

I have an array of rand numbers, and I have been looking of a function to know the index of the minimum value `min(x)`for example.

Imagine my array of rand numbers is this one:

`centopulos=array(1:150)`

So `min(centopulos)` will give me `1`. What if now I want to get the index of this `min` value (taking into  account that the array may not be sorted)?

I tried functions like:

`find(centopulos,min(centopulos))`

But obviously it has not worked. Is there a function in R to do that? I have searched and have not found any.

Comment: Have you tried `which.min(centopulos)`?

Comment: Works!! Thanks so much! @KoenV

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935199/how-to-identify-positions-of-max-value-in-an-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base are

```
which(centopulos==min(centopulos))
```

But maybe there is a more fancy way

Answer (score 1):

The shortest possible solution would be

```
which.min(centopulos)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it could be `match(min(centopulos), centopulos)`